# Unable to start server due following issues: Launch process failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, glassfish

For 3 days now, I have been trying to install glassfish 4.1 on eclipse Luna version 4.4.1. I first installed the plugin from eclipse marketplace then added it in my runtime using jdk 8. I also made jdk my default since eclipse default uses jre. I have to point out that I have been been using glassfish on netbeans and tomcat on eclipse but I decided to play around with glassfish on eclipse. Every information I got on the internet didn't fix my issue. 
Below is the error I got in the console. Right now, this is driving me nuts so I have decided to come to you for direction.
Thanks

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:131)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:645)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:131)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:135)
    ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: Does that cache directory exist? Can you create it?

Comment: Are you running as Administrator?

Comment: Hi Elliott, I don't have the osi-cache directory in C:Program Files/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domain/domain1/felix. If I am correct, I think that directory should be created from glassfish-4.1/glassfish/osgi/felix but it's not. What do you suggest? Thanks

Comment: Thanks PM 77-1, I finally got glassfish to start. I had to run asadmin as administrator and decided to create another domain instead of using the default domain1 created by glassfish since I have domain1 running for netbeans. From this point, I started the new server instance. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: Hi, I just have another question which I am not sure is an eclipse problem or a glassfish problem. Even after starting the server from asadmin, I still cannot deploy web projects directly from the eclipse workspace. I decided to see if I could restart the server from the eclipse workspace just to see what happens. It stops the server but would not start. The console shows Launching GlassFish on Felix platform C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\testDomain\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied))
The only way it can start is running asadmin as administrator.

Comment: I guess this is a similar problem. The cause may be that you have installed Glassfish in `c:\Program Files\`. You can try to move your Glassfish installation to a directory where your normal user account has full access rights but you then have to change the path to the Glassfish installation in Eclipse.

Comment: PS: If the comments solve your problem you should post the solution as an answer and accept this answer :)

Comment: Hi unwichtich, I will do just that as soon as the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Wow, I finally got it to work. Turns out that all the problems I had with the glassfish server (including exit code 1 error) was because glassfish could not handle folder names with spaces in it. So I moved the glassfish-4.1 folder from C:\\Program File path to C:\\ path. It wiped all my tears away. This is really important in eclipse and netbeans IDEs (if you are installing the netbeans that does not come with a glassfish bundled zip).

Answer (score 1):

Run Eclipse or any other IDE you use in Administrator mode.
Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your comment deserves to be posted as the main answer but I have been trying to mark your comment as answer but I wash't able to. So I decided to post post your comment here and then back it up with my own experience.

Answer by unwichtich:
I guess this is a similar problem. The cause may be that you have installed Glassfish in `c:\Program Files`. You can try to move your Glassfish installation to a directory where your normal user account has full access rights but you then have to change the path to the Glassfish installation in Eclipse.

My own experience:
Turns out that all the problems I had with the glassfish server (including exit code 1 error) was because glassfish could not handle folder names with spaces in it. So I moved the glassfish-4.1 folder from C:\Program File\glassfish-4.1.. path to C:\ glassfish-4.1.. It wiped all my tears away. This is really important in eclipse and netbeans IDEs (if you are installing the netbeans that does not come with a glassfish bundled zip).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by installing Glassfish under C:\ instead of C:\Program Files. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

use JDk 7 instead of JDK 8 am also faced the same issue i just changed to jdk7 its working now.